# How to implement Search in Dynamic Data Site in .NET 4 with LINQ to SQL Classes

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-dynamic-data

I just created a Default Dynamic Data Site. How Can I add search to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add search functionality by doing the following.

Firstly add the UI to the List.aspx page with the following code

```
<fieldset id="MultiSearchFieldSet" class="DD" runat="server" visible="False">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txbMultiColumnSearch" CssClass="DDTextBox" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnMultiColumnSearchSubmit" CssClass="DDControl" runat="server" Text="Search"
        OnClick="btnMultiColumnSearch_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnMultiColumnSearchClear" CssClass="DDControl" runat="server" Text="Clear"
        OnClick="btnMultiColumnSearch_Click" />
</fieldset>
```

Next, we want to add the code-behind for the Button, so on List.aspx.cs go down to

```
protected void btnMultiColumnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

And change it to

```
 protected void btnMultiColumnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            if (button.ID == btnMultiColumnSearchClear.ID)
                txbMultiColumnSearch.Text = String.Empty;
            else
                using (PhoneListDataContext Data = new PhoneListDataContext())
                {
                    EmployeeNameString = txbMultiColumnSearch.Text;
                    var SearchResults = Data.Employees.Where
                       (Employee => (Employee.FirstName.Contains(EmployeeNameString) || (Employee.LastName.Contains(EmployeeNameString))));


                    GridView1.DataSourceID = ""; 
                    GridView1.DataSource = SearchResults;
                    GridView1.DataBind();


                }
        }
```

And finally, beacause we are only searching the "Employees" table, I want to filter the visibility of the search box only to the employee's table.

So I add this code to **List.aspx.cs** in **protected void Page_Load**

```
 if (table.DisplayName == "Employees") { MultiSearchFieldSet.Visible = true; }     
            else
            { MultiSearchFieldSet.Visible = false; };
```

And now the page is Searchable!

Comment: The `var EmployeeNameString = txbMultiColumnSearch.Text;` line was missing the `var` from the beginning. Otherwise a valid tip, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***More simple solution***

- Create folder for your mything -table, note that the DynamicData-system uses plural name of your table (mything ---> mythings)

  - DynamicData\CustomPages\mythings\
- Copy DynamicData\PageTemplates\List.aspx to DynamicData\CustomPages\mythings\
- Edit DynamicData\CustomPages\mythings\List.aspx

**Change this line:**

```
 <h2 class="DDSubHeader"><%= table.DisplayName%></h2>
```

To this:

```
<h2 class="DDSubHeader"><%= table.DisplayName%></h2>
 <!-- Custom: 
    - Added SearchTextBox and SearchButton. 
        - Attention: Requires SearchExpression to work, 
        see next Custom -comment later in this page. 
--> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="DDBottomHyperLink">
                <a  href="<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>">Clear search filter</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- Custom ends -->
```

**Change QueryExtender**

From this:

```
        <asp:QueryExtender TargetControlID="GridDataSource" ID="GridQueryExtender" runat="server">
            <asp:DynamicFilterExpression ControlID="FilterRepeater" />
        </asp:QueryExtender>
```

To this:

```
        <!-- Custom: edit QueryExtender --> 
        <asp:QueryExtender TargetControlID="GridDataSource" ID="GridQueryExtender" runat="server">
            <asp:DynamicFilterExpression ControlID="FilterRepeater" />
               <asp:SearchExpression SearchType="Contains" DataFields="myfirstfield,mysecondfield,myNthfield" >
               <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchTextBox" />
            </asp:SearchExpression>
        </asp:QueryExtender>
        <!-- Custom ends -->
```

***Note*** change the *myfirstfield,mysecondfield,myNthfield* to the text field names at your **mything** -table.